# Newbie on Laravel working with relationship models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, tinker

I'm working to build up a Laravel API and I'm having dome troubles with the models relationships and not sure if I'm doing this well.

I have the following models on my project:

- Brand
- Category
- Kind
- Product
- Size
- ProductImages

This models represents the products available on a ecommerce and I'm trying to relate it the following way:

1 product has 1 brand + 1 category + 1 kind + n ProductImages (one product n images for every image belongsTo one product only) + n sizes (I would like to use the same size table row for multiple registers).

I want this related on the database so I from 1 product I can get all the related information such as brand or category but also I need to do it on reverse from one brand get all the products for example.

So I've started  doing the following model functions:

Brand:

```
public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Category:

```
public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Kind:

```
public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Product:

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }

    public function size(){
        $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
    }

    public function kind(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Kind::class);
    }

    public function productImages(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImages::class);
    }
```

Size:

```
public function product(){
        $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

ProductImages:

```
public function product(){
        $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

If I do query categories on Tinker I get the list of categories bu I f I try to get all the products belonging on a same category I get nothing but not sure if its right to relate all the models like I'm doing.

When I check product's brand on tinker this is what I get:

```
    >>> $product = App\Models\Product::First();
=> App\Models\Product {#4307
     id: "1",
     descrption: "Voluptatibus et eius enim aut ipsa earum quis veritatis.",
     productImages_id: null,
     size_id: null,
     brand_id: "1",
     category_id: null,
     kind_id: "1",
     created_at: "2021-03-01 11:19:18",
     updated_at: "2021-03-02 10:26:14",
   }
>>> $product->brand();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#4302}
```

MIgrations:

Products table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('descrption');
            $table->integer('productImages_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('size_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('brand_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('kind_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Brands table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Categories table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('category');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Sizes table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('size');
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Kinds table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kinds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->string('kind');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

ProductImages table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did all keys name are as per laravel standards ?

Comment: Yes they are. Would be useful if share the migrations too?

Comment: @TarangP I added the migration files

Comment: No need to post this much code. Please try to reduce your question with as little text as possible. It will help you think about it better and help others review the problem

Answer (score 0):

attach the query code part so we can check it out also you should follow carefully the naming convention of the forging keys between these tables, otherwise, you need to specify the forging key name in the relations method parameters.

update: so, you seem you are not triggering the query to get you the result

instead of

```
$product->brand();
```

do

```
$product->brand()->get();
```

also you can access it magically like:

```
   $brand = $product->brand;
```

Comment: I've added to the question the queries I run on tinker

Comment: Dont forget add return before $this->belongsTo. Check if the field are not null in the database. Check if the names of relations fields are standards. Last you could try

Comment: Dont forget add return before $this->belongsTo. Check if the field are not null in the database. Check if the names of relations fields are standards. Last you could try $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brand_id', 'id')  where brand_id is the field name in product table and id is the name of the primary key in brand table.

Comment: @kiewlovsky I have updated the answer check it out please

Answer (score 0):

The product your dump via tinker does not seem to have a category attached **(category_id=null)**.
Can you confirm how you are assigning a product to a category or a category to a product?

Comment: I've added the products through a seeder and the category is null but the brand it has a brand and it's returning nothing

Comment: can you share a snippet code from your seeder? Your seeder is not doing what you think is suppose to.

Comment: The seeder is ok at this point I just want to get the product's brand and all the products from the same brand and that info is being added to the database

Answer (score 0):

Please check that ->id() is not setting primary key on tables.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-id

Maybe you could use ->increments() to define the primary key field.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-increments

or ->primary('id') instead at final.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes

Answer (score 0):

After several modifications seems like the issue came from the migration files because the column that references the foreign key was set as integer to store the id and setting it as unsignedInteger and re-running the migrations solved the issue. This is the Products table migration file:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('descrption');
            $table->unsignedInteger('size_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('brand_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('kind_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```